# Swift Generics and enum as a data source

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a view which displays a list of options and provides the user an option to choose one of the options. This view must be reusable to use with multiple sets of options. How do i do it. I have tried the below approach but i got this error `Protocol 'Options' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` and I know why this is happening. Any better approaches?

```
protocol Options: CaseIterable {
    var displayName: String { get }
}

enum MyOptions: Options {
    case hello
    case mello
    case fello
    
    static var allCases: [MyOptions] {
        [.hello,.mello]
    }
    
    var displayName: String {
        "hello"
    }
}

/// This is just for testing

func testContains(option: Options, options: [Options]) -> Bool {
    true
}

print(testContains(option: MyOptions.fello, options: MyOptions.allCases))
```

Comment: Would [OptionSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) workfor you?

Comment: These are unrelated sets of options. Dont think OptionSet would make sense

Comment: I don't think generics will help you.  Looking at your declaration of `MyOptions` it is essentially recreating `OptionSet`.  The other approach is just to use a string raw value with your enum

Comment: For example: I would have different types of options like, BaseOptions, ToppingOptions, PackagingOpitons which can be displayed in the same reusable view. How would option set help me here

Comment: It may not.  It was just when I saw your code, you are essentially recreating `OptionSet`. You haven't shown exactly how you want to use the various option in your view.  Your protocol would need more than just `displayName`

Comment: It's just displaying `displayName` of each enum case

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `testContains` method to be generic with a type constraint to `Options`.

```
func testContains<T: Options>(option: T, options: [T]) -> Bool {
    true
}
```

Comment: It's not just this one function, It is used in multiple places like 30/40 places. Any another approach you can think of

Comment: @Kiran then you need to make all of those functions generic. What's wrong with that? Another possible solution would be to do type erasure, but that would require even more changes to your code.

Comment: The problem is I am not able to pass the variable around, In order to do that, I have to make my views generic, my view controller generic and a lot of other things generic.For ex: I want to store the value of the currently selected option in my view state, I cant do `var selected option: Option` I have to make my view state generic

Comment: How would type erasure help us here?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply CaseIterable to enums that need it, rather than putting it at the base protocol. If having CaseIterable in the base is a requirement, then @Dávid Pásztor is correct that you have to use type erasures or generics.

```
//
// used to be 'protocol Options: CaseIterable {'
//
protocol Options {
    var displayName: String { get }
}

// I just moved CaseIterable down from the base.
enum MyOptions: Options, CaseIterable {
    case hello
    case mello
    case fello

    static var allCases: [MyOptions] {
        [.hello,.mello]
    }

    var displayName: String {
        "hello"
    }
}

/// This now compiles and runs
func testContains(option: Options, options: [Options]) -> Bool {
    true
}

print(testContains(option: MyOptions.fello, options: MyOptions.allCases))
```